# Executing anonymous PL/SQL block

Tags: sql, plsql

The question is asking for an anonymous PL/SQL block that:
      declares a variable that counts all products in Products table
      has an if-else statement depending on whether count is >= or < 7

**My try so far:**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  number_of_products NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(product_id)
  INTO number_of_products
  FROM products
  IF number_of_products >= 7 THEN --Syntax error on this line, not sure why
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The number of products is greater than or equal to 7');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The number of products is less than 7');
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An error occurred');
END;
```

**Error messages:**
    
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
    
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
    
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
    
ORA-06550: line 9, column 3:
    
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSE" when expecting one of the following:
   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
    ORA-06550: line 12, column 1:
    
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" 
    
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

What am I missing?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I just added the error messages to the original post.

Comment: semi colon at the end of the sql query?

Comment: where? i doubled checked all semicolons

Comment: @Zeus might be right, and also, don't use `WHEN OTHERS THEN` then make it output using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`. its bad practice.

Comment: try what you see in answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  number_of_products NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(product_id)
  INTO number_of_products
  FROM products;
  IF number_of_products >= 7 THEN --Syntax error on this line, not sure why
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The number of products is greater than or equal to 7');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The number of products is less than 7');
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An error occurred');
END;
```

Comment: Hmm, it worked like a charm, but I can't see which part you changed?

Comment: @SummerBoy `FROM products;`  in the select query.